# WP_Query() does not return all entries

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this query that returns only a few of the entries I have on the table. I have over 10 posts but this query only returns 6. Please help with suggestions

```
$query = new WP_Query("year=2011&monthnum=09&post_status=publish&post_type=post&orderby=post_date&order=DESC");
while ($query->have_posts()):
    $query->the_post();
    $title=get_the_Title();                                                                                                                  
    echo"<p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"MyArticle[]\" value=\"".get_the_ID()."\">".get_the_Title()."</p>";
endwhile;               
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: `"year=2011&monthnum=09&post_status=publish&post_type=post&orderby=post_date&order=DESC"` is the driving force in the `WP_Query` class. My guess would be that 4 of the posts don't have a proper year, month, or published status.

Answer (score 107):

Try adding `posts_per_page=-1` to the string of parameters passed to `WP_Query`.

If that value is not set, then it falls back to use the default posts per page option you have set in `Settings >> Reading >> Blog pages show at most`.

My guess is that this value is 6 so its returning that many posts since you did not specify a different limit.

Comment: This would be the correct answer, whether clicked answered or not. Thank you

Comment: This fixes the issue of the Query not returning anything at all. This happens onces posts reach a certain age. This brings them all back!

Comment: Thanks @drew010.. I was held up for listing the pages for 2 days.. Thanks a lot.. posts per page helped me

Comment: That worked for me. but can anybody tell what is the logic behing it??

Comment: @ArshadHussain -1 is just what wordpress is programmed to look for in order to have no limit on posts, and if no value is passed then it looks at the blog settings for a default value.  They actually document it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) now and you can see it in the source [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2260)

Comment: Thanks also for pointing out where the default value came from!

Comment: @drew010 the arbitrary  6  is not anywhere in the WP_QUERY documentation as far as I can tell. I was trying to figure out why I could only  had 6 custom menu locations, and this finally solved the problem for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 22):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```