# I am getting max category post count = 10, every time

Tags: php, post, categories

I have some categories and each category have some subcategories.

For example :

```
Entertainment(slug = 'entertainment')
--- Movies
--- Drama
--- Sports
```

I want to retrieve the number count of all posts in `entertainment` and its sub categories

But max count i am getting is 10 everytime.When there is total 13 posts its 10 but if less than 10 posts its exact number. it return 8 for 8..but 10 for 13

### My code is

```
function PrinzPostCatCount( $slug ){
    // category posts count
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'category_name'     => $slug, 
    );
    $post = new WP_Query( $args );
    return (int) $post->post_count;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WP\_Query() does not return all entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943236/wp-query-does-not-return-all-entries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `'posts_per_page'=>-1` with the query.

i.e.

```
$post = new WP_Query( array('category_name' => $slug, 'posts_per_page'=>-1) );
```

Comment: Possibly add why it limits to 10 now :) (I'm guessing a default value)